# Roaming user profile not loading

Tags: windows-8.1, user-profiles, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a user on active directory who has a roaming profile set up. I have the address in the profiles tab like so:

[image: profiles tab]

However, when I try to login to a computer using the profile, I get a message "The user profile could not be loaded and you have been logged in using a temporary profile." I can access \\iceman\profiles$\dzabel.V2 using windows explorer when logged in as the user, and even create and delete files. I am unsure what could be causing Windows to do this.

Comment: Yes, but I believe that it is added by Windows Vista and later to differentiate profiles from XP. I shouldn't have to add that there. It also does the same thing with adding .V2 to the end.

Comment: Good luck.  Your response was sort of rude.